# Segment selector and plain pointer

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-architecture

Assume I want to take the stack-pointer to use it later in C code, and for some reason would like to do that in assembly, like this (x86, 32 bit):

`asm("\t movl %%esp,%0" : "=r"(my_p))`

Will `my_p` really point to the stack or should I also take `ss` into consideration?

Comment: All mainstream operating systems use flat memory (except for TLS and such) so you do not need to use `ss`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

32-bit and 64-bit x86 modern versions of Windows, Linux, and macOS initialize the `SS` register to a fixed value and never change it after that. So you don't have to capture `SS`. You can refer to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_memory_segmentation) article to know more about how x86 segmentation was used in the past and how it's currently being used.

However, in Real Mode or Protected Mode (without paging), `SS` may change, especially when switching from one thread or task to another. If a program is running in one of these modes, then you should capture `SS` as well. Note that `SS` can be changed using `LSS`, `MOV`, or `POP`. These instructions can be executed at any privilege level.